# HTML / PHP - How to "pack components into multipart documents"?

Tags: php, html, performance, header, multipart

Seems like a straightforward question but there must be something I'm missing.

Perusing the famous Yahoo "high performance frontend" recommendations, I came across the phrase

> Pack components into a multipart document

and then short brief blurbs which didn't really elaborate very much on the how-to side of things.

I know there's a multipart header, and that emails are split using multipart boundaries, but further searching hasn't revealed much more...can someone explain what the heck this means and what situations it applies to?

Comment: i believe its only a suggestion for mobiles

Comment: Ah, the blurbs suggested that. Actually, there was a tag that said "mobile" but I couldn't extrapolate much information from that :)

Comment: following poorly explained suggestions from random web sites is probably not a good ides :-)

Comment: Fair enough, but poorly explained suggestions from Yahoo's performance gurus... ;)  http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#multipart

Comment: one man's guru another mans charlatan - don't believe everything you read :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multi-part documents, I believe, only works well with IE; the idea is to pack the HTML and all images into one document (like how mime emails work).

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

I wouldn't go down this route; I think it's better to just aggressively cache your external scripts, images and style sheets. It's just more practical and in most cases will yield the same performance.

Comment: +1 thanks Jack - you mean, everything's just dumped into a stream, like base-64 encoding an @font-face?

Comment: @Steve the encoding can be anything; the main design of MHTML is like how `multipart/form-data` is constructed; the HTML is in the first part, the "attachments" are in the other parts.